# How to build ASP.NET web site the way VS2008 does using msbuild?

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

With web sites in VS2008 (the ones without .csproj files), a build does a kind of validation where the site is 'compiled' to nowhere, and web site dependencies are copied into the web site's Bin directory.

I want to do this exact process but at the command-line using msbuild.  That is, I want an msbuild task that my msbuild target can execute that validates the web site, reporting any compile errors and copying dependencies to Bin, but does *not* require an IIS virtual directory, and does not precompile all the aspx and other files to DLLs in the Bin directory.

The AspNetCompiler task appears to do a full precompile, creating a directory full of compiled aspx pages.  And it requires an IIS virtual directory.  So I don't think this task will work for me.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked VS [Web Deployment Project](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx)  . Also, take a look at [aspnet_merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397866.aspx) tool since you are concerned

> The AspNetCompiler task appears to do
>   a full precompile, creating a
>   directory full of compiled aspx pages.

And I don't think aspnet_compile requires an IIS virtual directory

Comment: I may be reading that page wrong, but it looks like that's a "take your built web site and deploy it" tool, whereas I need to build it in place, and just minimally the way VS2008 does.  Thanks though.

Comment: The tool actually does the build for you. I am not sure what do you mean "in place", even VS2008 will compile your page into "deployable" folder.

Comment: Take a look at this link : http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deployment-tool/

Comment: +1 for the various good ideas... although aspnet_merge is not what I'm looking for.  I don't want any compiled dlls at all.  I just want dependency dlls (assembly references) copied into Bin and that's it.

Comment: Then why not run msbuild against your solution file or your project file?

Comment: heh heh.  You know, while we were discussing these other ideas, I was wondering the same thing.  I don't have a project file for the web site, but I do have a sln file, and apparently the target to build is named after the web site.  Add another answer and I'll accept it.